# How to set asp-for in a for loop

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a for loop to generate fields on a form.

How can I set the value of **asp-for** based on the current index?

`<label asp-for=@("Value" + i) class="control-label"></label>` does not work.

Comment: Eh what? It's unclear what you're asking. In asp-for you pass the models property in. Are you confusing that with the HTML's `<label for="someid">` ?! When you loop through an array you already have the reference to the item. i. . `foreach(var item in Model) { ...}` then you have a reference to `item`, so you can use it in `asp-for` like `asp-for="item.Value"` or `asp-for="item.Name"` depending on  how your properties on the model class are named

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? What is the output of `@("Value" + i)` ? what did you expect instead ? Is there an error message ?

Comment: You can't. The value passed for `asp-for` must be a `ModelExpression`. It can't take a generic string value representing a property. FWIW, though, having properties like `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3`, etc. is pretty much always wrong. Use a collection type, instead: i.e. `Values`. Then, what you're attempting to do here is trivial, since you're just indexing that collection, which *can* be expressed as a `ModelExpression`.

Comment: Tseng>>>My model has several properties Value1...Value31. Based on some condition I need to either provide an input field or a hidden field. So the for loop is more like `for(int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) { /* tag helper for each property */ }`

Wndrr >>> I get an error *InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single...*

Answer (score 8):

You can bind the model with an index like so using ether `foreach` or `for`:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    int i = 0;
}
<form method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {

        <input asp-for="Items[i]" />
        i++;
    }

    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Items.Count; j++)
    {

        <input asp-for="Items[j]" />
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Items = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
    }

    public void OnPost(List<string> items)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is a bit of how it works:

In this controller you have 2 action, one returns a list of strings which will be out model. And the second action will accept a parameter as a list of strings.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View(new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" });
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Test(List<string> Words)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Now in our Test view `Test.cshtml` file, we want to display this list of string with their index and when we change these values we want to be able to post them.

```
@model List<string>

@{
    int i = 0;
}

<form method="post">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <label>@item  - @i</label>
        <input name="Words[@i]" value="@item" />

        i++;
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

And after submitting the form, the values in the input fields will appear in the list of strings, because of the html `name` attribute.

You have to understand that the tag helper `asp-for` is used by Razor to generate all sorts of html attributes on the field such as name/id/data-* etc... the main thing you need is the `name` attribute to bind the value.

Comment: This is the same idea that @ChritPratt was proposing.

I was looking for something along the line of:
    `@for(int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        <label asp-for="Value"+i />
        <input type="number" asp-for"Value"+i />
    }`

This way I don't have to write 62 lines for my 31 properties

Comment: I missed List<> and changed it to '@model List<Model>'. Eventually, it worked well.

Comment: @Daleman how did you put `asp-for` ?